# Model Evolvement architectural design query

Tags: c#, .net, oop, mvvm, model

ViewModel, Model, MVVM Architecture Problem.

Once upon a time I used to define a model class as follows:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName;
  public string LastName;
}
```

Few years later, I understood it is a better idea to define a model class as follows:

```
public class Person
{
  private string firstName;
  private string lastName;

  public string FirstName {get{ return firstName;} set{ return firstName; } }
  public string LastName  {get{ return lastName; } set{ return lastName;  } }
}
```

and why.. because generally it allowed more versatility, in example:

```
public class Person
{
  private string firstName;
  private string lastName;

  public string FirstName {get{ return firstName;} private set{ return firstName; } }
  public string LastName  {get{ return lastName; } private set{ return lastName;  } }

  public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
      this.firstName = firstName;
      this.lastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

Few months later the auto-properties introduced and again things became easier:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName  {get; set;}
}
```

And the versatility remains:

```
public class Person
{
  public string FirstName {get; private set;}
  public string LastName  {get; private set;}

  public Person(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
      FirstName = firstName;
      LastName = lastName;
  }
}
```

And even another goodie if we go to the class without the private setters:

```
var myInstance = new Person{FirstName = "Che", LastName="Guara"}
```

So far - excellent.

But now we have another evolvement which MVVM really wants us to use.. (in the model!)

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private string firstName;
  private string lastName;

  public string FirstName
  {
    get{ return firstName; }
    set
    { 
       firstName = value;
       if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName");
    } 
  }

  public string LastName
  {
    get{ return lastName; }
    set
    { 
       lastName = value;
       if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName");
    } 
  }
}
```

So.. ok.. it is not as short as before but it is acceptable.

But if evolvements of the model is something, well natural..

And it is agreed that "Don't Repeat Yourself" is a good principle.

In many cases I will not need a specific View-Model class - but not in all cases.

And that's ok.

Why would it be wrong to change the entire attitude toward object-centric paradigm?

In example:

```
publie interface IPersistable
{ 
   Guid Id {get;set;}
   DataAccessLayer Dal {get;set}
   void Persist();
   void Populate();
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged, IPersistable
{
  public DataAccessLayer Dal;

  private Guid Id;

  public Guid Id
  {
     get {return id;}
     set
     {
    id=value; 
    if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Id");
     }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private string firstName;
  private string lastName;

  public string FirstName
  {
    get{ return firstName; }
    set
    { 
       firstName = value;
       if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName");
    } 
  }

  public string LastName
  {
    get{ return lastName; }
    set
    { 
       lastName = value;
       if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("LastName");
    } 
  }

  public void Persist() //assume this is part of IPersistable.
  {
    Dal.Persist(this);
  }

  public void Populate() //assume this is part of IPersistable.
  {
    var t=Populate(Id);
    FirstName = t.Firstname;
    LastName = t.LastName;
  }

}
```

So somewhere in the a module I can do, just in example:

```
myObj.Persist();
```

Is this a wrong idea or a good idea? Good Architecture or Bad Architecture?

There is still separation of concerns in it - just written differently.

Really busting my head over it, will appreciate your input on this.

Thanks.

G.Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `INotifyPropertyChanged`: MVVM asks you to use it on ViewModels, because WPF utilizes this interface for databinding between the View and its `DataContext` which is the ViewModel in MVVM. Apart from that, `INPC` is only an interface for the notification of property changes and can be used everywhere you like. People usually think that it is not supposed to be implemented in models, which is wrong but also you don't have to. You only need to implement `INPC` on your model, if you want to use it somewhere, probably most often to handle these changes in the ViewModel. If your model only changes due to manipulations by the ViewModel, there is no need to implement `INPC` for example.

In other words: The model is agnostic of the fact that it is used in an MVVM pattern.

Therefore, don't think about the whole system too much when you design your model: It provides change notification: fine, it provides persistence functions: fine, it's a perfectly fine OOP class. That's enough for the model to be a good model for MVVM.

**EDIT:**

The question is not MVVM specific imo. It makes sense to ask, whether representing an entity (a person in this case), notifying of property changes (again, INPC is not MVVM specific) and maintaining persistence are too many concerns for one class. Notification and persistence are a kind of service function and you still separate the actual logic in your Dal. So, sure why not, if it makes sense in your application to individually save and load the entities, why would you mind? What are your actual concerns why you shouldn't do that? Of course, a class with two properties would be nicer, but it's always a trade-off...

In short: I think holding data, maintaining this data's persistence and notifying changes sound like a nice bundle of jobs to put into a class.

Let me know whether this answers your questions satisfyingly.

Comment: I agree with what you write in general - but not with - model is agnostic of the fact it is used in an mvvm pattern.. as there is no reason to include inpc in the model unless you work with mvvm in practice - however I do accept that inpc included is as you say perfectly fine oop class. however it is not answering my question.. Is the last class I put in the example which imply a different approach of "object-centric" approach or "model-centric" approach is good practice or not? if it is ok to put inpc, why not let the model handle its own persistence as well in the way the example shows?

Comment: There are many reasons to implement INPC in models apart from MVVM. For example I have calculations which mark themselves as dirty if referenced object's properties have changed. On the other hand, there are lots of scenarios where your model doesn't need INPC. INPC itself is nothing MVVM specific.You just need a different trigger to synch your VM (periodically, or after pushing changes to the model). Anyway, that's academic... As I said, your approach is perfectly valid in my eyes. I've extended my answer.

Comment: Thank you, yes - it does satisfy my question :)